# MySQL join Query for three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables:

```
asset_details
------------------------------
asset_no    asset_type_id
------------------------------
AS1     id1
AS2     id2
AS3     id1
AS4     id3
AS5     id1
--------------------------------

asset_customer_mapping
--------------------------------
asset_no    customer_site_id
--------------------------------
AS1     site1
AS2     site1
AS3     site2
AS4     site4
AS5     site1

asset_type_mst
-------------------------------
asset_type_id   asset_type_name
-------------------------------
id1     Desktop
id2     Laptop
id3     Printer
id4     Plotter
id5     Router
```

Now i need the following result from mysql:

```
SiteName | Desktop | Laptop | Printer | Plotter | Router | Total
-----------------------------------------------------------------
site1   |    2     |  1     |    0    |    0    |    0    |  3
site2   |    1     |  0     |    0    |    0    |    0    |  1
site3   |    0     |  0     |    0    |    0    |    0    |  0
site4   |    0     |  0     |    1    |    0    |    0    |  1
site5   |    0     |  0     |    0    |    0    |    0    |  0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Total   |    3     |  1     |    1    |    0    |    0    |  5
```

I have wriiten the below query to group the customer_site_ids

```
select b.customer_site_id,count(*) from asset_details a,asset_customer_mapping b,asset_type_mst c
where a.asset_no=b.asset_no and a.asset_type_id=c.asset_type_id
group by b.customer_site_id;
```

But I am not able to get the type-wise separation to get the required result. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: there is only 5 value in asset_type_mst? or your want this to be dynamiclly?

Comment: There will be more than 5 values in the asset_type_mst, but it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @fs='';

select @fs:=concat(@fs,'sum(if(asset_type_name=\'',asset_type_name,'\',1, 0)) as ', asset_type_name, ',')
    from (select distinct asset_type_name from asset_type_mst) A;

set @statq=concat('select ifnull(customer_site_id, \'total\') sitename,', @fs, 'count(1) as total',
              ' from asset_details d join asset_customer_mapping c on d.asset_no = c.asset_no',
              ' join asset_type_mst a on d.asset_type_id=a.asset_type_id',
              ' group by customer_site_id WITH ROLLUP');

prepare stmt from @statq;
execute stmt;
```

sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e48a0/23)

First declare a `fs` to combine the dynamic `sum(if)` statement using all `asset_type_name` from  `asset_type_mst`.
Then prepare a statment using concat the dynamic sum(if) statment `fs` to the normal group by statment.